# how do hidden or delete the header field in bootstrap-vue b-table?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

for some reason, I don't want to show the fields of `b-table` in my web. In other words, I don't want to show the table head fields.

But I never find how to hidden or delete the fields(such as Information field name) in bootstrap-vue.

Please help me.

And I have another question, why can I get the value of items by `cell(information)="row"`.

here is my test code, you can run it on playground.

Thank you in advance for you help.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table
      striped
      hover
      :items="items"
    >
      <template v-slot:cell(information)="row">
        <p>{{row.item.information.test1}}</p>
        <p>{{row.item.information.test2}}</p>
      </template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { information: { test1: 1, test2: 1 } },
        { information: { test1: 3, test2: 3 } },
        { information: { test1: 2, test2: 2 } },
        { information: { test1: 4, test2: 4 } }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to completely hide the `thead` of the table, you can add `thead-tr-class="d-none"` to your `b-table`. This will completely hide the `thead`.

`thead-tr-class` can be found under the [property reference](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#comp-ref-b-table-props) of `b-table` on the Bootstrap-Vue documentation.

`d-none` is a bootstrap utility class which can be found [display utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/display/), on the Bootstrap documentation.

Comment: Oh, my god. It is a perfect solution.But I didn’t find it in the official documentation, can you tell me where you found it？Thanks for your help.@Hiws

Comment: @hey6775 I added links to documentation where both the class and the prop can be found.